# How to tile texture with MixedRealityToolkit shader and Round Corners?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I'm trying to make an animated material with the MRTK in Unity. The goal is to make an effect with look like starting with a circle and propagating the texture to rest of the plane.

For now I use the MixedRealityToolkit standard shader and use the round corner option. With an animation I made that :

[image: Plane animation]

My problem is that I can't tile the texture to reduce the size of the texture and repeat it. Also for non-square object, the texture is stretched and it's not really nice.

[image: Plane's texture stretched]

If I try to change the tile setting, the texture is not repeated (texture is well in "Repeat Mode", it works when I untick Round Corners option)

[image: Texture is not repeated]

(If I display Unity selection outline, I obtained the repeated texture, but it's not displayed ... )

[image: Unity selection outline]

Does anyone have a good idea to do that with the MRTK shaders or how to write a specific shader for this effect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, writing my own shader :

```
Shader "Custom/testShader"
{

Properties
{
    _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _ForegroundMask("Foreground Mask", 2D) = "white" {}
    _RadiusSize("Radius size", Range(0,2)) = 0
    _BorderWidth("Smooth Edge width", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
    _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
    _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
}
SubShader
{
    Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
    LOD 200

    ZWrite Off
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

    CGPROGRAM
    // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
    #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows alpha:fade

    // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
    #pragma target 3.0

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    sampler2D _ForegroundMask;

    struct Input
    {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
        float2 uv_ForegroundMask;
    };


    half _Glossiness;
    half _Metallic;
    fixed4 _Color;
    float _RadiusSize;
    float _BorderWidth;

    // Add instancing support for this shader. You need to check 'Enable Instancing' on materials that use the shader.
    // See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html for more information about instancing.
    // #pragma instancing_options assumeuniformscaling
    UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
        // put more per-instance properties here
    UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
    {

        fixed2 dist;
        dist.x = IN.uv_ForegroundMask.x - 0.5;
        dist.y = IN.uv_ForegroundMask.y - 0.5;

        fixed circle=  1.0 - smoothstep(_RadiusSize-(_RadiusSize * _BorderWidth),_RadiusSize+(_RadiusSize * _BorderWidth), dot(dist,dist)*4.0);

       
        fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
        
        o.Albedo = c.rgb;
        // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
        o.Metallic = _Metallic;
        o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
        o.Alpha = c.a * circle;


    }
    ENDCG
}
FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```